# Ruby - Split the string and store it in a Array based on the first word

Tags: ruby

I am pretty much new to Ruby and I am looking at the best way to do the below.

I have a string like this `"Account 1 - Name, Account 1 - Age, Account 2 - Name, Account 2 - Age"`

I am looking for an output something like this

```
[[Account 1, Name], [Account 1, Age], [Account 2, Name], [Account 2, Age]]
```

Certainly I don't want to post the ways I tried as it looks silly and ugly. I am looking for a single liner if possible. Many thanks and appreciate all your help!

Comment: @Joseph gives the normal solution, but you could also write `str.split(/ - |, /).each_slice(2).to_a`. `str.split(/ - |, /)  #=> ["Account 1", "Name", "Account 1", "Age", "Account 2", "Name", "Account 2", "Age"]`. See [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) (the "no block given" case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks pretty straightforward. You need to split once based on `,`, and then again based on `-`. The first `split` already stores your data into an array for you so you don't need to do anything else.

```
string = "Account 1 - Name, Account 1 - Age, Account 2 - Name, Account 2 - Age"
array = string.split(', ')
array = array.map { |acc| acc.split(' - ') }
# [[Account 1, Name], [Account 1, Age], [Account 2, Name], [Account 2, Age]]
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much! Since I am new to Ruby, I was not aware of the map method. May be I missed reading the document or it did not strike me when I went through the docs. Got to know about it now!

Comment: @shank087 sure thing! I edited my answer you gotta reassign `array` if you don't use `map!`